# Make `find` returns only sub-relative path in Linux？

Tags: linux, find

I am using `find` in Ubuntu to list all files in one directory into a text file. With the command below:

```
find ./ -name "*.txt"
```

I get results:

```
./a.txt
./dir/b.txt
```

But I want the results to be like:

```
a.txt
dir/b.txt
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: `find * -name "*.txt"`

Comment: Or you could pipe the output to a command that removes the first two characters of each line, like `cut -c 3-`

Comment: `find ./ -name "*.txt" -printf "%P\n"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar, the below commad works:

```
find * -name "*.txt"
```

If you want sorted output:

```
find * -name "*.txt" | sort
```

If you want to save the output into txt file:

```
find * -name "*.txt" | sort > res.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to use simple `ls` command. With `**` glob pattern to recurse sub-directories.

```
shopt -s globstar
ls {,**}/*.txt
```